# RSS Feed "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT" Due To Permalink Change

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, rss

I have read a lot of posts about fixing this issue, but have not been able to resolve it.

I changed my permalinks setting, and now my RSS feed no longer works.

I get following error:

```
"This web page has a redirect loop. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
```

> URL: http://micloud.azurewebsites.net/
>
> NOTE: WordPress site is running in Microsoft Azure as a "Web App", NOT a custom VM deploy with manual installation of WordPress.
>
> WP Version: 4.2.2

I have disabled all of my plugins, and reverted back to default permalink setting, but am presented with the following message when accessing the RSS feed:

```
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
```

I am looking for a way to "reset" the RSS feed mechanism, to re-generate itself based on the new permalink settings.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have some issue with your feed generation/url script under: http://micloud.azurewebsites.net/feed/

it keeps responding with 302 status code - temporary redirect with location set to itself hence redirect loop, here is your response header when you visit: http://micloud.azurewebsites.net/feed/

```
Remote Address: 23.101.169.175:80
Request URL: http://micloud.azurewebsites.net/feed/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Temporary Redirect
```

have a look into the source code of the script responsible for handling http://micloud.azurewebsites.net/feed/ or your htaccess as there might be some weird redirect being set.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no reset button in wordpress, please consider reinstall wordpress in azure, **I suggest you backup your database first**, if this doesn't help you, please try to use "WordPress Database Reset" plugin to reset your specific database table that may cause error, refer to https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-reset/ for more details.